# How to use order in find_each rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I really do not know whether someone has already asked this question or not, if someone has already asked this, please let me know.

I want to use order with find_each. It should something like

```
Email.find_each(:order=> "id desc").do |email|
  puts "email.id"
end
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hey guys thanks for your solutions, but I have found my solution, so if anyone wants to use it.
If you are not using find_each any where else in your program then you can override ActiveRecord's batches method and for that.

```
create a file active_record.rb in config/initializers
```

In that you just have to change

```
if primary_key_offset
  records= relation.where(table[primary_key].lt(primary_key_offset)).to_a
end
def batch_size
  "#{quoted_table_name}.#{quoted_primary_key} DESC"
end
```

Answer (score 23):

Since `find_each` internally uses `find_in_batches`, which forces order to be ascending on the primary key (`id ASC` by default) and doesn't allow to change it, it's not possible.

More info here:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html

Comment: Still is there's any possibility, where I can override or customize find_in_batches method for the order.

Comment: find_each now allows you to specify :desc or :asc on the primary key. https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html#method-i-find_in_batches

Comment: Since Rails 6.1 you can pass an `order` argument `User.find_each(order: :desc)` https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/30590

Answer (score -7):

```
Email.all.sort {|a, b| b[:id] <=> a[:id]}.each do |email|
  puts "email.id"
end
```

Comment: This would fetch **all** emails and then iterate through them. There's a reason `find_each` is used in the question. -1.